# How to manipulate the multiple mask created in the Flash IDE from AS3 code

Tags: flash, mask

I use Flash CS5.5. Manually i created few layers and some of them apply shape mask that created on one of layer.
[here look image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqxK5.png)

Then i manipulate with childrens (addChild, removeChild) from AS3 code. After that the masking is disappear 8(. I encountered a problem that every children object has no mask with code below.
    `for(var i:uint=0; i < this.numChildren; i++)
    {
        trace("poster["+String(i)+"] =",this.getChildAt(i),"mask =",this.getChildAt(i).mask);
        //poster[0] = [object Shape] mask = null
        //poster[1] = [object PosterItemsContainer] mask = null
        //poster[2] = [object PosterItemsContainer] mask = null
        //poster[3] = [object PosterItemsContainer] mask = null
        //poster[4] = [object PosterItemsContainer] mask = null
        //poster[5] = [object PosterBut_3] mask = null
        //poster[6] = [object PosterBut_3] mask = null
        //poster[7] = [object PosterBut_3] mask = null
        //poster[8] = [object PosterBut_3] mask = null
        //poster[9] = [object TextField] mask = null
        //poster[10] = [object TextField] mask = null
    }`

Of course i can create all these children dinamically from AS3 code and then probably will be no problems whith mask property, but in this case i have to create the container for masking objects. I want to try create one level nesting and deal with the mystical Flash IDE layer mask.